# QueryFilterBuilder elastic search 2.4

Tags: elasticsearch

I hav ethis piece of code now as of elastic search 2.4 QueryFilterBuilder  is deprecated and its showing error.
QueryFilterBuilder queryFilterBuilder = FilterBuilders.queryFilter(esQueryBuilder); i tried to replace it with QueryBuider but its not accepting.

```
 if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(textQuery)) {
  QueryBuilder esQueryBuilder = CatalogKeywordSearchHelper.getAppropriateESQueryForUserQuery(storeId, textQuery);
  QueryFilterBuilder queryFilterBuilder = FilterBuilders.queryFilter(esQueryBuilder);
  filterBuildersMap.put(IdxSchemaConstants.TEXT_QUERY, queryFilterBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query filters have been deprecated in ES 2.0 and since then queries can now be used in a filter context, you can simply use a `bool/filter` query and put your query in it:

```
 if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(textQuery)) {
    QueryBuilder esQueryBuilder = CatalogKeywordSearchHelper.getAppropriateESQueryForUserQuery(storeId, textQuery);

    # change this line
    BoolQueryBuilder queryFilterBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .filter(esQueryBuilder);

    filterBuildersMap.put(IdxSchemaConstants.TEXT_QUERY, queryFilterBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Whatever has replaced has been merged to BoolQueryBuilder